# Setting cmake's msvc compilers flags on command line using git bash

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, git-bash

Can someone help with the following issue. I'm using Cmake + git bash and on the windows machine with msvc compiler. If I configure project in the following way `cmake ..` everything works fine and I can see the following output:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28319.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28319.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
```

However, when I try to set compiler flags `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/MD" ..` I get the following error:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28319.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28319.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:53 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/dev/projects/camshare/microservices/templates/microservice_cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_ce8fa.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28319 for x64
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
      Program
      cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_ce8fa.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_ce8fa.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue  C:/Program Files/Git/MD C:\dev\projects\camshare\microservices\templates\microservice_cpp\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx
    c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:/Program': No such file or directory [C:\dev\projects\camshare\microservices\templates\microservice_cpp\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_ce8fa.vcxproj]
      MD
    c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Files/Git/MD': No such file or directory [C:\dev\projects\camshare\microservices\templates\microservice_cpp\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_ce8fa.vcxproj]
      testCXXCompiler.cxx
      Generating Code...

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

If I try to do the same with windows cmd everything works fine. Can you explain where is the problem and how I can fix it? Looks like compiler flags were incorrectly appended (strange Files/Git/MD on the command line). I've also tried `CXXFLAGS="/MD" cmake .." and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in git bash mangling of forward slashes, solution can be easily found. Closing the question.